# JavaScript form validation to check if username and password are correct for a login

Tags: javascript, python, html, validation, flask

I used a js file to check if username and password are correct for a login. The js file contains a single username and password that work and I want to know how safe it is, I use flask so I can do the validation in the backend, Is it better or is it also unsafe?

The correct username and password according to the js file:
username = "username"
password = "password"

js file:

```
function validateForm() {
    let x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
    let y = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
    let username = document.getElementById('errorUsername');
    let password = document.getElementById('errorPassword');

    if (x != "username" && y != "password") {
      username.style.visibility = "visible"; 
      password.style.visibility = "visible"; 
      return false

    }
    else if (x == "username" && y != "password"){
      username.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
      password.style.visibility = "visible"; 
      return false
    }
    
    else if (x != "username" && y == "password"){
      username.style.visibility = "Password"; 
      password.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
      return false
    }

    else {
      return true
    }
  }
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="center">
  <h1>login</h1>
  <form action="/login" method="POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <div class="txt_field">
      <input type="text" name="username" required autocomplete="off">
      <label for="username">username</label>
    </div>
    <small id=errorUsername>Incorrect username</small>
    <div class="pass"></div>
    <div class="txt_field">
      <input type="password" name="password" required>
      <label id=sisma for="username">password</label>
    </div>
    <small id=errorPassword>Incorrect password</small>
    <div class="pass"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    <div class="signup_link"> <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Python file in the backend:

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        session['logged_in'] = username
        return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
        
    return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: _I want to know how safe it is_ Not safe, anything in the client will be available for the users. If you do the check there, they can just read the credentials. Even if you hash them, they can check the code to see what you send in case of a successful login and send that directly. You need to manage the login from the backend you control.

Answer (score 0):

How safe is it having usernames or passwords embedded in your javascript? **Not at all safe, in the slightest bit**. Obviously, you are just doing some kind of test here, because the design wouldn't make sense for an actual app with real users, but the principle of the thing is this:

All such validation needs to be done on the server, or authentication service.

You should always treat any authentication data as a "cockroach motel" --> the passwords go in and they don't come out. Ever.

In your sample code, it looks like you are helping the user fix the field they got wrong, but you don't want to do that either:

When a username/password combo fails, you should not tell the user what the problem is. Just that the combo doesn't work. They can fix whatever they need to fix, or start the password recovery process.

---

There are a couple of other suggestions for your sample code:

1. Using "username" and "password" as your test data are very confusing, because they are also the names of fields. It can be hard to read this and understand that this is suppsed to be data, and not the name of some object or property.
2. Using x and y as variable names makes it hard to track. Variable names should always describe what they are supposed to contain. Even professional programmers make the mistake of opting for short, cryptic variable names, but you will *never* regret choosing good variable names.